# Passing type of template function to template class used within it?

Tags: c++, templates, class, function

I am trying to build a template function.  Inside templated classes are used and I would like to pass the template type of the function to those classes.  So I have:

```
template <class T>
T find_bottleneck (ListGraph &g, CrossRefMap<ListGraph, Edge, T> &weight, Node &s, Node &t) {
    // Check if theres a single edge left
    if (countEdges(g) == 1) {
        CrossRefMap<ListGraph, Edge, T>::ValueIt itr = weight.beginValue();
        return *itr;
    }
```

However this fails, citing

```
lemon_graph.cpp: In function ‘T find_bottleneck(lemon::ListGraph&, lemon::CrossRefMap<lemon::ListGraph, lemon::ListGraphBase::Edge, T>&, Node&, Node&)’:
lemon_graph.cpp:20: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘itr’
lemon_graph.cpp:21: error: ‘itr’ was not declared in this scope
```

I tried to recreate this using a simple example of a function which generates vectors based on the type passed to it and that compiled fine, so I am not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Would a simple "return *(weight.beginValue());" work?

Comment: You're making a _function template_ in a _class template_.

Comment: @sbi: I am?  I thought find_bottleneck was a function template

Comment: I was referring to your "template function....templated classes". It's _function template_ and _class template_. (As trivial as this difference might sound, it's important. A _class template_ is not a class, it's a template from which classes can be generated. That's why you cannot use the class template's name where a type is expected: `std::vector<std::deque>` won't compile, because `std::deque` is _not_ a class. `std::deque<int>`, however, is, so `std::vector< std::deque<int> >` works. It's similar for function templates.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a missing `typename`.

```
typename CrossRefMap<ListGraph, Edge, T>::ValueIt
```

`typename` is the answer to at least 50% of all C++-template-related questions :-) It tells the compiler that what follows is always a type, regardless of the template parameters (`ValueIt` could for example be a `int` instead of a `typedef` for an iterator).

Comment: ah ok, thanks! I thought it was typename but I was trying

CrossRefMap<ListGraph, Edge, typename T>::ValueIt

Comment: @zenna: The rule is to always consider typename when you see `::`. typename is always applied to the "result" of an `::` operator.